# How to convert an address into a Google Maps Link

Tags: php, google-maps, hyperlink

I have the following code that is pulling an address in from a database.

```
 <td class="center"><?php echo ($customer->address!='')?$customer->address:'NA';?></td>
```

And displaying the address on an admin area.

i would like the address to be linked to google maps using

```
<a href="maps.google.com/?p= {then the addy} "> {the addy} </a>
```

But when i add the link to the code the code breaks.

The most recent attempt was

```
<td class="center"><a href="http://map.google.com/?p=<?php echo ($customer->address!='')?$customer->address:'NA';?>"><?php echo ($customer->address!='')?$customer->address:'NA';?></a></td>
```

Comment: What does an actual address look like?

Comment: 1292 Sherwood Mills Boulevard, Mississauga, ON, Canada

Comment: That would be https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=1292+Sherwood+Mills+Boulevard,+Mississauga,+ON,+Canada. As said in my answer below, replace all the spaces for '+'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your code is fine and should work just change your google address to https://maps.google.com/maps?q=

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do for a valid Google Maps URL is just to go to http://maps.google.com, type in the address you want to have and click on the 'link button'.
You can strip down to a shorter version which still works.
So for example: 1 5th Avenue, Manhattan, New York would be something like
https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=1+5th+Avenue,Manhattan,New+York,United+States.
So just add ',' between the parts of the address and a '+' for each space.

Comment: Putvande - a link like http://maps.google.com/?q=1200 Pennsylvania Ave SE, Washington, District of Columbia, 20003 works and the + is added automatically. 

That is what i would like to do. 

The address's are with in a database, and the database are leads so when i login i want to be able to click the addy they typed in and pull up google maps.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you want exactly. Can you explain a bit better what you actually want?

Comment: a lead will enter an address 555 main street,  I will log in to my admin area and see they typed in 555 main street. 

and i need to turn straight text from the database into a link.